# Can I apply a function to a pandas dataframe asyncronously?

Tags: pandas, asynchronous, python-asyncio

In my use case I need to fetch data from remote server. The code is roughly equivalent to:

```
def get_user_data(user_id):
    time.sleep(5)
    ...
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['uid1', 'uid2', 'uid3', ..., 'uid9999']})

answer = df['user_id'].apply(get_user_data)
```

It seems to me pandas could be running the `get_user_data` function asynchronously.

Note:
I've tried `df['user_id'].swifter.apply(get_user_data)` and using `dask`. They both give me an good speedup by running multiple functions in parallel, but my CPU, network, and remote server utilization remain very low.

Is there a way to do an asynchronous `.apply()` ?

Comment: I assume `get_user_data` is doing some IO-bound work? Then I might make sense to convert it to a coroutine and just loop over your dataframe without using apply. I think it heavily depends on your actual implementation of `get_user_data`. If it's CPU-bound then there is no use in looking into anything async.

Comment: It's doing an over-the-network retrieval of data, so I think it makes sense.